# Updating BIOS, won't recognize battery is plugged in

Tags: windows-7, command-line, updates, windows-xp, bios

I have a Dell Inspiron E1505 running Windows XP. I am trying to upgrade to Windows 7, but it tells me I first need to update my BIOS.

I downloaded the BIOS file and have tried running it, but it gives me an error saying that I need to plug in my AC adapter and battery before running the update; both seem to be fine. I have also gone into the command line and used `/forceit /nopause /forcetype` in different combinations but none work to skip this problem.

I can't write to a floppy disk as some people have recommended, because my laptop doesn't have a floppy disk drive. Dell customer support ends after the two year warranty so I am desperate to try to find help on fixing this update problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a floppy image to [make a bootable dos CD](http://www.biosflash.com/e/bios-boot-cd.htm), all you do is add the Dell MM061A17.exe to the floppy image and then convert to CD image. Boot from the Cd, this will put you at the DOS A prompt, then type MM061A17.exe and hit enter.